# is it possible to put a background image to an svg?

Tags: css

I have seen that they put `background images` to `paths`, but I want to know if it is possible to do it for the general `svg`, something like when for example I put a `background-image` to the `body` tag in `html`

```
 <svg height="500" width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: please change `height` spelling. `heigth` not.

Comment: Yes it is possible, have you tried setting `background-image: url()` and providing an SVG to the body? I just tried on CodePen and it works fine. [Helpful article](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/06-using-svg-svg-background-image/#:~:text=SVG%20images%20can%20be%20used,PNG%2C%20JPG%2C%20or%20GIF.&text=All%20the%20same%20awesomeness%20of,like%20flexibility%20while%20retaining%20sharpness.)